# Why do we use Euler-Lagrange equation for quantum fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle

I think in quantum fields we need Heisenberg equation to get Equation of Motion, while Euler-Lagrange equation is simply a classic field equation. Then why do we always use Euler-Lagrange equation to derive Equation of Motion from a known Lagrangian?

Comment: We _don't_! I think this is a pedagogical flaw of many QFT textbooks. A good half of these books are actually talking solely about classical field theory, where Euler-Lagrange works. If you think you've seen a specific example where Euler-Lagrange is applied to the quantum case, you should post more context.

Comment: @knzhou: Why do you say we don't? The classical equations of motion hold as "operator equations", i. e. "inside the path integral"/"inside expectation values" which is a special case of a Schwinger-Dyson equation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I know about that, but I don't think that's what the OP is confused about.

Answer (score 5):

It is important to distinguish between the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian formulation.

1. In the [Lagrangian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are the classical equations of motion, derived from the [stationary action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). In QFT, the EL equations continue to hold in quantum average, cf. the [Schwinger-Dyson equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation).
2. In the [Hamiltonian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics), the Heisenberg equations of motion are the quantum version of Hamilton's equations.